# Asking iAP purchase only once

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIButton where I can request to the user to buy iAP using that code :

But if a quickly press more than once time to the button, the UIAlertView is showed every time if I cancel the purchase. 
Comment if is needed a most part of iAP code.
How to display it only once a time?

```
@IBAction func book(sender: UIButton) {
         self.buyConsumable()
    }


    func buyConsumable(){
         if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments())
        {
            let productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: self.productID!);
            let productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>);
            productsRequest.delegate = self;
            productsRequest.start();
        }else{

        }
    }
...
```

Comment: what about disable the button until the `StoreKit` calls you back via delegate?

Comment: Not a bad way to do that

Comment: @holex put comment as an answer

Comment: somebody else needs the reputation more than I'd. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@IBAction func book(sender: UIButton) {

     sender.enabled = false
     self.buyConsumable()
}


func buyConsumable(){
     if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments())
    {
        let productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: self.productID!);
        let productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>);
        productsRequest.delegate = self;
        productsRequest.start();
    }else{

    }
}
```

Once the payment is done **sender.enabled = true**